# $D^b_\text{Coh}(X)$ for a smooth, proper Deligne-Mumford stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories, algebraic-stacks

Let $X$ be a smooth, proper DM stack over a field $k$. I see in Hall-Rydyh's paper "Perfect Complexes on Algebraic Stacks" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.1887) a discussion of compact generation of $D_{qc}(X)$, the unbounded derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves. Is there a way to understand the bounded derived category $D^b_\text{Coh}(X)$ from $D_{qc}(X)$ in this setting?

To clarify: I am looking for references on how to view $D^b_{\text{Coh}}(X)$ as an $A_\infty$-category here.